# Is Visual Studio 2012 Express a good development environment for SharePoint 2013

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, tfs

I need to set the development environment for SharePoint 2013.; so will VS 2012 express version be suitable or it will lack the support for SharePoint templates as mentioned in this MSDN link:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms349441.aspx.

And in case i get the VS professional edition can i still use the Team foundation server express version with it , or the TFS express will not support SharePoint integration as mentioned in this link:-

http://lajak.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tfs-2012-versions-of-team-foundation-server/

Comment: Not sure about the SharePoint templates - but you **will be able** the use the TFS Express also with a Visual Studio Professional Edition.

Comment: thanks for the reply,i know that i can use the TFs express with VS professional , but since TFS express does not support integration with SharePoinr while VS professional do. So will in this specific case the TFS express can intigrate with sharePoint.